# Reading Basic Diode Circuits Without Connecting Wires Shown

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

In circuits like the one shown here, I am confused because i’m used to seeing wires connecting everything like in my last 2 circuit analysis classes. Notice the circles at each end. How can I redraw this to better understand how to read these?

[image]

Comment: Imagine (or draw) a voltage source between each of those terminals and ground, providing the indicated voltage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward. Normally you would see a ground symbol instead of 0V. The other voltages on the schematic are node voltages, and (for your purposes) they can be treated like ideal voltage sources connected between the node and ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTkCyE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Normally one does not draw power supply connections explicitly on a schematic. Instead one just indicates what power rail a device is connected to.

In the case of an analysis problem like this you can assume all the power rails are held at the relevant voltage by some external source. You could draw on explicit voltage sources, but I don't see the point.

Generally solving a problem like this requires some back and forth between reasoning and calculation. For two of the diodes it should be immediately obvious whether or not they are conducting. For the third diode it's not so clear, so run the numbers both ways and see which numbers make sense.

In the case of a full design that is actually intended to be built then the power rails will need to be supplied from somewhere, but that somwhere may be off on a different

Comment: Is it possible to redraw these for the sake of learning to read them? It is really just a visual problem I have with seeing where things are connected. I will try to redraw it and post a picture.